# How to make this drop down menus appear on click rather than on hover?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was following a tutorial on how to create this nice looking sidebar that expands when hovering and fade in elements but it has a dropdown menu that expands when hovering as well (the desktop version) and I need it to expand only when clicking it.

If you hover over Profile and Notifications menu items they toggle when hovering and I need it to toggle when click.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--========== BOX ICONS ==========-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">

    <!--========== CSS ==========-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/styles.css">

    <title>Responsive sidebar submenus</title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--========== HEADER ==========-->
    <header class="header">
        <div class="header__container">
            <img src="https://pruebaapp.ga/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/profile-1-150x150.jpeg" alt="" class="header__img">

            <a href="#" class="header__logo">YOUR LOGO</a>

            <div class="header__search">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="header__input">
                <i class='bx bx-search header__icon'></i>
            </div>

            <div class="header__toggle">
                <i class='bx bx-menu' id="header-toggle"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <!--========== NAV ==========-->
    <div class="nav" id="navbar">
        <nav class="nav__container">
            <div>
                <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__logo">
                    <i class='bx bxs-disc nav__icon' ></i>
                    <span class="nav__logo-name">Bedimcode</span>
                </a>

                <div class="nav__list">
                    <div class="nav__items">
                        <h3 class="nav__subtitle">Profile</h3>

                        <a href="#" class="nav__link active">
                            <i class='bx bx-home nav__icon' ></i>
                            <span class="nav__name">Home</span>
                        </a>
                        
                        <div class="nav__dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                                <i class='bx bx-user nav__icon' ></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">Profile</span>
                                <i class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon'></i>
                            </a>

                            <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
                                <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Passwords</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Mail</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Accounts</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                            <i class='bx bx-message-rounded nav__icon' ></i>
                            <span class="nav__name">Messages</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="nav__items">
                        <h3 class="nav__subtitle">Menu</h3>

                        <div class="nav__dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                                <i class='bx bx-bell nav__icon' ></i>
                                <span class="nav__name">Notifications</span>
                                <i class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon'></i>
                            </a>

                            <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
                                <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
                                    <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Blocked</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Silenced</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Publish</a>
                                    <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Program</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                        </div>

                        <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                            <i class='bx bx-compass nav__icon' ></i>
                            <span class="nav__name">Explore</span>
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" class="nav__link">
                            <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav__icon' ></i>
                            <span class="nav__name">Saved</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__logout">
                <i class='bx bx-log-out nav__icon' ></i>
                <span class="nav__name">Log Out</span>
            </a>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <!--========== CONTENTS ==========-->
    <main>
        <section>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt vel illum fuga unde cum, voluptates magni molestias eveniet culpa autem ut, totam veniam, suscipit tempore ullam pariatur est at asperiores?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt vel illum fuga unde cum, voluptates magni molestias eveniet culpa autem ut, totam veniam, suscipit tempore ullam pariatur est at asperiores?</p>
            <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt vel illum fuga unde cum, voluptates magni molestias eveniet culpa autem ut, totam veniam, suscipit tempore ullam pariatur est at asperiores?</p>
        </section>
    </main>

    <!--========== MAIN JS ==========-->
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

I have made a pen with this element so you can see it:

https://codepen.io/henrymendeez/pen/rNjNNdw

Comment: Please review [ask] & provide a [mcve] when asking a question. Your question currently includes many lines of code that are irrelevant to the question being asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Replace this:

```
/* Show dropdown collapse */
.nav__dropdown:hover {
  max-height: 100rem;
}

/* Rotate icon arrow */
.nav__dropdown:hover .nav__dropdown-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

With this:

```
/* Show dropdown collapse */
.nav__dropdown.open {
  max-height: 100rem;
}

/* Rotate icon arrow */
.nav__dropdown.open .nav__dropdown-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

---

2. Add this to the javascript:

```
const navDropdown = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__dropdown");
for (let i = 0; i < navDropdown.length; i++) {
  navDropdown[i].addEventListener("click", () =>
    navDropdown[i].classList.toggle("open")
  );
}
```

---

---

This is what we get:

```js
/*==================== SHOW NAVBAR ====================*/
const showMenu = (headerToggle, navbarId) => {
  const toggleBtn = document.getElementById(headerToggle),
    nav = document.getElementById(navbarId);

  // Validate that variables exist
  if (headerToggle && navbarId) {
    toggleBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // We add the show-menu class to the div tag with the nav__menu class
      nav.classList.toggle("show-menu");
      // change icon
      toggleBtn.classList.toggle("bx-x");
    });
  }
};
showMenu("header-toggle", "navbar");

/*==================== LINK ACTIVE ====================*/
const linkColor = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__link");

function colorLink() {
  linkColor.forEach((l) => l.classList.remove("active"));
  this.classList.add("active");
}

linkColor.forEach((l) => l.addEventListener("click", colorLink));

const navDropdown = document.querySelectorAll(".nav__dropdown");
for (let i = 0; i < navDropdown.length; i++) {
  navDropdown[i].addEventListener("click", () =>
    navDropdown[i].classList.toggle("open")
  );
}
```

```css
/*========== GOOGLE FONTS ==========*/

@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600&display=swap");

/*========== VARIABLES CSS ==========*/

:root {
  --header-height: 3.5rem;
  --nav-width: 219px;
  /*========== Colors ==========*/
  --first-color: #6923d0;
  --first-color-light: #f4f0fa;
  --title-color: #19181b;
  --text-color: #58555e;
  --text-color-light: #a5a1aa;
  --body-color: #f9f6fd;
  --container-color: #ffffff;
  /*========== Font and typography ==========*/
  --body-font: "Poppins", sans-serif;
  --normal-font-size: 0.938rem;
  --small-font-size: 0.75rem;
  --smaller-font-size: 0.75rem;
  /*========== Font weight ==========*/
  --font-medium: 500;
  --font-semi-bold: 600;
  /*========== z index ==========*/
  --z-fixed: 100;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
   :root {
    --normal-font-size: 1rem;
    --small-font-size: 0.875rem;
    --smaller-font-size: 0.813rem;
  }
}


/*========== BASE ==========*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: var(--header-height) 0 0 0;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0;
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  background-color: var(--body-color);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

h3 {
  margin: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}


/*========== HEADER ==========*/

.header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(22, 8, 43, 0.1);
  padding: 0 1rem;
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
}

.header__container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: var(--header-height);
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.header__img {
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.header__logo {
  color: var(--title-color);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  display: none;
}

.header__search {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.4rem 0.75rem;
  background-color: var(--first-color-light);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.header__input {
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: var(--first-color-light);
}

.header__input::placeholder {
  font-family: var(--body-font);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.header__icon,
.header__toggle {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

.header__toggle {
  color: var(--title-color);
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*========== NAV ==========*/

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 0;
  background-color: var(--container-color);
  box-shadow: 1px 0 0 rgba(22, 8, 43, 0.1);
  z-index: var(--z-fixed);
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.nav__container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding-bottom: 3rem;
  overflow: auto;
  scrollbar-width: none;
  /* For mozilla */
}


/* For Google Chrome and others */

.nav__container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  display: none;
}

.nav__logo {
  font-weight: var(--font-semi-bold);
  margin-bottom: 2.5rem;
}

.nav__list,
.nav__items {
  display: grid;
}

.nav__list {
  row-gap: 2.5rem;
}

.nav__items {
  row-gap: 1.5rem;
}

.nav__subtitle {
  font-size: var(--normal-font-size);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.1rem;
  color: var(--text-color-light);
}

.nav__link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.nav__link:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__icon {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.nav__name {
  font-size: var(--small-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.nav__logout {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}


/* Dropdown */

.nav__dropdown {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 21px;
  transition: 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.nav__dropdown-collapse {
  background-color: var(--first-color-light);
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.nav__dropdown-content {
  display: grid;
  row-gap: 0.5rem;
  padding: 0.75rem 2.5rem 0.75rem 1.8rem;
}

.nav__dropdown-item {
  font-size: var(--smaller-font-size);
  font-weight: var(--font-medium);
  color: var(--text-color);
}

.nav__dropdown-item:hover {
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.nav__dropdown-icon {
  margin-left: auto;
  transition: 0.4s;
}


/* Show dropdown collapse */

.nav__dropdown.open {
  max-height: 100rem;
}


/* Rotate icon arrow */

.nav__dropdown.open .nav__dropdown-icon {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}


/*===== Show menu =====*/

.show-menu {
  left: 0;
}


/*===== Active link =====*/

.active {
  color: var(--first-color);
}


/* ========== MEDIA QUERIES ==========*/


/* For small devices reduce search*/

@media screen and (max-width: 320px) {
  .header__search {
    width: 70%;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  body {
    padding: 1rem 3rem 0 6rem;
  }
  .header {
    padding: 0 3rem 0 6rem;
  }
  .header__container {
    height: calc(var(--header-height) + 0.5rem);
  }
  .header__search {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0.55rem 0.75rem;
  }
  .header__toggle {
    display: none;
  }
  .header__logo {
    display: block;
  }
  .header__img {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    order: 1;
  }
  .nav {
    left: 0;
    padding: 1.2rem 1.5rem 0;
    width: 68px;
    /* Reduced navbar */
  }
  .nav__items {
    row-gap: 1.7rem;
  }
  .nav__icon {
    font-size: 1.3rem;
  }
  /* Element opacity */
  .nav__logo-name,
  .nav__name,
  .nav__subtitle,
  .nav__dropdown-icon {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
  }
  /* Navbar expanded */
  .nav:hover {
    width: var(--nav-width);
  }
  /* Visible elements */
  .nav:hover .nav__logo-name {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav:hover .nav__subtitle {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav:hover .nav__name {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  .nav:hover .nav__dropdown-icon {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<!--========== BOX ICONS ==========-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/boxicons@latest/css/boxicons.min.css">

<header class="header">
  <div class="header__container">
    <img src="https://pruebaapp.ga/wp-content/uploads/2021/03/profile-1-150x150.jpeg" alt="" class="header__img">

    <a href="#" class="header__logo">YOUR LOGO</a>

    <div class="header__search">
      <input type="search" placeholder="Search" class="header__input">
      <i class='bx bx-search header__icon'></i>
    </div>

    <div class="header__toggle">
      <i class='bx bx-menu' id="header-toggle"></i>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<!--========== NAV ==========-->
<div class="nav" id="navbar">
  <nav class="nav__container">
    <div>
      <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__logo">
        <i class='bx bxs-disc nav__icon'></i>
        <span class="nav__logo-name">Bedimcode</span>
      </a>

      <div class="nav__list">
        <div class="nav__items">
          <h3 class="nav__subtitle">Profile</h3>

          <a href="#" class="nav__link active">
            <i class='bx bx-home nav__icon'></i>
            <span class="nav__name">Home</span>
          </a>

          <div class="nav__dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              <i class='bx bx-user nav__icon'></i>
              <span class="nav__name">Profile</span>
              <i class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon'></i>
            </a>

            <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
              <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Passwords</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Mail</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Accounts</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <a href="#" class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-message-rounded nav__icon'></i>
            <span class="nav__name">Messages</span>
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="nav__items">
          <h3 class="nav__subtitle">Menu</h3>

          <div class="nav__dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="nav__link">
              <i class='bx bx-bell nav__icon'></i>
              <span class="nav__name">Notifications</span>
              <i class='bx bx-chevron-down nav__icon nav__dropdown-icon'></i>
            </a>

            <div class="nav__dropdown-collapse">
              <div class="nav__dropdown-content">
                <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Blocked</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Silenced</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Publish</a>
                <a href="#" class="nav__dropdown-item">Program</a>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>

          <a href="#" class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-compass nav__icon'></i>
            <span class="nav__name">Explore</span>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="nav__link">
            <i class='bx bx-bookmark nav__icon'></i>
            <span class="nav__name">Saved</span>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a href="#" class="nav__link nav__logout">
      <i class='bx bx-log-out nav__icon'></i>
      <span class="nav__name">Log Out</span>
    </a>
  </nav>
</div>

<!--========== CONTENTS ==========-->
<main>
  <section>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt vel illum fuga unde cum, voluptates magni molestias eveniet culpa autem ut, totam veniam, suscipit tempore ullam pariatur est at asperiores?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt vel illum fuga unde cum, voluptates magni molestias eveniet culpa autem ut, totam veniam, suscipit tempore ullam pariatur est at asperiores?</p>
    <p>Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Incidunt vel illum fuga unde cum, voluptates magni molestias eveniet culpa autem ut, totam veniam, suscipit tempore ullam pariatur est at asperiores?</p>
  </section>
</main>
```

---

[Check it in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/xxgxGeg)

---

---

If you want the dropdown to close when nav is closed then add this to the script:

```
const main = document.querySelector("main");
main.addEventListener("mousemove", (e) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < navDropdown.length; i++) {
    navDropdown[i].classList.remove("open");
  }
});
```

[Check it in action on Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/abpbZaq)

Comment: thank you very much! This is what I was looking for. Do you know how to make this to un-toggle when clicking outside? If you open any of the dropdown submenu it will stay open even if you click outside or if  you move the mouse to another place. Right now it un-toggles when clicking on other menu element.

Comment: @henrymendeez I have added new code at the end ✌.

Comment: The last update did the work! Awesome! One last favor, can you please make it un-toggle when clicking outside the item? If I click on Profile or Notifications it doesn't un-toggle if I click on whitespace on the sidebar. The first part to un-toggle when moving the mouse away is done, now its only missing the un-toggle when clicking outside.

Comment: @henrymendeez That it to simple, you can so the same...

Comment: I'm at a very beginner level with JavaScript so it's not so easy for me to make this modifications. Do you know how to make the sidebar un-toggle when clicking on the bars icon on the header and also when clicking anywhere outside (on mobile)? And for desktop, un-toggle it when clicking in a whitespace or on any other menu element inside the sidebar? Your help is very appreciated.

Comment: @henrymendeez That is a lot of work... You needed help I did... nobody else does. If I started doing this, then first you will not learn anything and 2) That is my job and if I started doing it like this then every body will misuse it?

Comment: I understand. The help you gave me was awesome! I will make some searching on my own. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

```
.nav:hover {
    width: var(--nav-width);
  }
```

change to

```
.nav.active {
    width: var(--nav-width);
  }
```

then in your js you add that class on the element when you click it

Comment: Thanks for the answer but what I need is the Sub Menu items toggle when clicking it rather then hovering it.